# Timer in a child thread not working

Tags: multithreading, qt

I've seen similar questions about this, but my situation is a bit different from others.

I have a `main` class that creates an instance of a `child` class. The `child` class needs to have a timer to do a particular action every 1 milliseconds. My problem is that the *timer* timeout action does not happen.

```
class mainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
   private:
      child *Child;

   public:
      void action()
      {
          QThread *childThread = new QThread(this);
          Child = new child();
          child->moveToThread(childThread);
          childThread->start();

          Child->action();
      }
}


class child : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
protected:
   void timerEvent (QTimerEvent *){/*some code here*/}
public:
   void action()
   {
      this->startTimer(1);
   }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Thank you in advance

Let me know if you need any more information

Comment: Nitpick, but a class called "main" in C++? I am sure you are aware of that it is also the name of the entry point in an application (i.e. main function). It would be better if you could use "mainwindow" instead which seems to be common a naming schema.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: Yes, you're right, this is just a sample code I wrote here to demonstrate, anywany I will change it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `child->action` call must be executed in that object's thread. There are two ways to fix it:

1. Start the timer before you move the `child` object to its thread. The timer will be restarted in the new thread.

   ```
   QThread *childThread = new QThread(this);
   Child = new child();
   Child->action();  
   Child->moveToThread(childThread);
   childThread->start();
   ```
2. Invoke the `action` slot in `child`'s thread context:

   ```
   QMetaObject::invokeMethod(child, "action");
   ```